# Starting an Activity from a Service

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to start a Android Activity or App, when a push notification is received using a Service?

This only starts a new Activity, when the App is already running...

This is called in a Service when a push notification is received.

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
this.startActivity(in);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible (but possible, see my edit below).

Even if it was possible, do you think it is a good idea that an activity suddenly pops up out of nowhere and replaces anything you were doing? I would surely uninstall this app right away and give it the worst possible rating.

I suggest you show a notification instead.

---

After thinking about it, it is possible. You can launch any activity using `am start -n` through the shell, however I strongly discourage you from doing so. The standard method is showing a notification.

Comment: I need that to open the App when a phone call is incomming. Would it be possible to play a ringtone in the background instead of this. In my case it only worked when the app was open.

Comment: Your question is already answered. "Would it be possible to play a ringtone" is a totally different question, which you can post as a new question.